# Error to compile a .Net Core 1.0.4 project in VS 15: Microsoft.DotNet.Props missing

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, sdk

When I Start my project This message shows up.

"The following error occurred attempting to run the project model server process (1.0.4).

[image: 1.0.4]

This  is the configuration in .csproj:

```
PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">14.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
```

When I click on this project properties I can't see any information about .Net Framework it's running.

[image: No information here]

Then,i try to build and this shows up:

Error   MSB4019 The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" was not found

Well, there is no Microsoft.... folder after ..\sdk\1.0.4.

I have installed the latest DotNet Core Version and the Preview 2 for visual studio 15.

I've tryed alot of install and updates, none of then worked:/

What am I  missing ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to install all 3 files: SDK, SDK tools, Runtime according to this offical link: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/sdk